# Error When Force Resolving Android Dependencies in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor, android-unity-plugin

**The Error Log was:**

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

**Here's the Player Setting and the error logs**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue, I created JAVA_HOME variables in Environment Variables System Properties and copied the directory of of UNITY IDE's default installation folder for JDK

[image]